# column Aliases is turning lowercase but i want it as i define

Tags: sql

I am creating columns naming them using Aliases as how i want, but no matter what case i use, finally i see only lowercase headers in the table. how can i get what i want.

```sql
CREATE table schemaName.tablename AS
SELECT   action
FROM     schemaName.differentTableName AS "Upper.Action"
```

i currently get

```
action
data1
data2
data3
```

what i want is

```
Action
data1
data2
data3
```

Comment: aliasing the selected result has no effect in the actual result returned, simply update the differrnttable to have uppercase valus

Comment: I strongly recommend to **not** use quoted identifiers. They give you much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: @NikosM.: the alias **will** be used for the column name in the table that is created.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i thought the selected column data needed to be uppercase and aliasing the selected column has no effect on this, anyway

Answer (score 3):

Your SELECT statements assign an alias to the table, not the column. You need to use a quoted **column** alias

```
create table schemaName.tablename as
select action as "Action" 
from schemaName.differentTableName;
```